# Can't start nginx - no errors anywhere

Tags: nginx

I am unable to start nginx using the `service nginx {signal}`.

```
root# service nginx status
 * /usr/sbin/nginx is not running
root# service nginx start
root# service nginx status
 * /usr/sbin/nginx is not running
root# ls -al /run/*.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root    5 Jul 23 17:32 /run/acpid.pid
root# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx   [fail] 
root# ls -al /run/*.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root    5 Jul 23 17:32 /run/acpid.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root    0 Jul 25 17:06 /run/nginx.pid
root# service nginx status
 * /usr/sbin/nginx is not running
```

Inside `/var/log/nginx/error.log` there is only one entry:

```
2014/07/25 16:59:52 [notice] 17085#0: signal process started
```

However, neither top, nginx, or netstat show nginx is actually running.

Since I built from source, where might nginx be dying? Where are the log files? `/var/log/syslog` doesn't seem to have anything about this. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm can't add comment :(
file size /run/nginx.pid = 0, nginx can't write pid to file.

start script can't find pid master process
I suspect you need to diff:
pidfile in /etc/init.d/nginx  and pid in nginx.conf

Comment: Yep, the `/etc/init.d/nginx` was looking for `/run/nginx.pid` while the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` had `pid /var/run/nginx.pid` in it. On Ubuntu `/run` and `/var/run` are `ln -s`, but it wasn't working until I fixed that. Strange.

Comment: Also, note that `/etc/init.d/nginx` uses `grep` against `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to find the `pid` location which means you can NOT comment a `pid ...` line out and expect all to be well!

Comment: Hello, I have same problem. How did you fix it please ? My both files are lookig for `pid /run/nginx.pid`.